# Assertion Error in Pypdf package in Python

Tags: python, pypdf

I am using Python 2.4 and PyPdf 1.13 on a Windows platform. 
I am trying to merge PDF files from a list into one using the following code:

```
import os
from pyPdf import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

attached=["C:\\test\\T_tech.pdf","C:\\test\\00647165-Backup.pdf"]
output=PdfFileWriter()
maxpage=0

os.chdir("C:\\test")
name= attached[0]
name = os.path.basename(name).split('.')[0]

for nam in attached:
   input= PdfFileReader(file(nam,"rb"))  
   maxpage=input.getNumPages()
   for i in range(0,maxpage):
     output.addPage(input.getPage(i))

outputStream =file("Output-"+name+".pdf","wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

I am getting the following error when I run this code.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python24\pdfmerge.py", line 13, in ?
       input= PdfFileReader(file(nam,"rb"))
    File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 374, in __init__
       self.read(stream)
    File "C:\Python24\Lib\site-packages\pyPdf\pdf.py", line 847, in read
       assert False
  AssertionError
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

From the source:

```
            # bad xref character at startxref.  Let's see if we can find
            # the xref table nearby, as we've observed this error with an
            # off-by-one before.
            stream.seek(-11, 1)
            tmp = stream.read(20)
            xref_loc = tmp.find("xref")
            if xref_loc != -1:
                startxref -= (10 - xref_loc)
                continue
            else:
                # no xref table found at specified location
                assert False
                break
```

You're hitting that latter "no cross reference table found..." condition.  Try patching the source, omitting the assertion and see if it still works.

Comment: This may has something to do with the fact he is using Python 2.4. I cannot reproduce the error with Python 2.7.2 on Windows.

Comment: Hi Brian, Thanks for your try. I tried it by commenting it out but still no change.

Comment: "no change"?  That seems really unlikely.  At a minimum, if you're somehow hitting another assertion failure it should be on a different line.

Comment: I found the error is due to one of the files being used is a scanned PDF. Is there any way I can merge scanned PDF?

Comment: I don't see any reason why not.  Those are just pages with a huge raster image in them.